# Integer not updating although method should force it

Tags: java, integer

So, I'm creating a text based game in Java and the currency is jellybeans. I have an issue, though. Whenever I set the currency to add 5, it doesn't, and returns 0. Here's the code

```
public class Util{

    public int Jellybeans = 0;

    public void jellybeans(int Amount){
        Jellybeans = Jellybeans + Amount;
    }

    public int getJellybeans(){
        return Jellybeans;
    }
}


public class Tutorial{

    Util util = new Util();
    private int jellybeanCount = util.getJellybeans(); 

    private void dialog(){
        //unrelated irrelevant stuff
        util.jellybeans(5);
        Util.printAnimatedText("You now have " + jellybeanCount + " 
        jellybeans!")'
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, this is probably a basic issue but I'm not sure

Comment: Yes, it's a basic issue.  `jellybeancount` is a copy of whatever `getJellybeans` returned at the time you did the assignment.  It doesn't change when `getJellybeans` changes.  It's like, I have a piece of paper with a 5 written on it, and tell you to get your own piece of paper and copy mine.  If I then cross out the 5 on my piece of paper and change it to a 6, does your piece of paper change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're invoking the `getJellybeans()` in the wrong place. What you need to do is:

```
Util util = new Util();
private int jellybeanCount; 
private void dialog(){
    util.jellybeans(5);
    jellybeanCount = util.getJellybeans(); // here
    Util.printAnimatedText("You now have " + jellybeanCount + " 
            jellybeans!")'
}
```

**Why is that?**

Because when you create the `Util` object at the beginning, the `Jellybeans` field is yet **empty** (or particularly equals **ZERO**). So when you invoke the `getJellybeans()`, the field is still has no 5 yet and returns its initial value **ZERO**.

But the after setting the value of the field to 5 `util.jellybeans(5);`, you then HAVE a field with a value in it other than zero. You can get now.

Comment: I think it works, right, but... why create a new variable if you already have it in the class?

Comment: @DamianLattenero It's not creating a new variable, it's assigning a value to the above field (`private int jellybeanCount;`).

Comment: Yes yes! sorry, I was talking about that field :). Why is needed?

Comment: @DamianLattenero The OP did not ask for code optimization, he was just asking why the integer is not updating.

Comment: Mmm...  fair enough, in that case is a plus one then :)

Answer (score 3):

> Edit

If you really want to have a `jellybean` counter, and encapsulate it, you should do a few extra things:

```
public class Util{

    private int Jellybeans = 0; //make this variable private, so you only expose it and edit it via getters and setters

    public void jellybeans(int Amount){
        Jellybeans = Jellybeans + Amount;
    }

    public int getJellybeans(){
        return Jellybeans;
    }
}


Util util = new Util();
//private int jellybeanCount = util.getJellybeans(); // this is not needed
private void dialog(){
    //unrelated irrelevant stuff
    util.jellybeans(5);
    Util.printAnimatedText("You now have " + util.getJellybeans() + " 
    jellybeans!")' // here you use the getter, so you have full control of the state of util class
}
```

this way, you encapsulate the behavior of your object inside the `Util` class, that's way you have a class, with an instance variable in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You are not calling the getJellybeans() methods after calling jellybeans(5).

```
    private int jellybeanCount = util.getJellybeans(); 
    private void dialog(){
        //unrelated irrelevant stuff
        util.jellybeans(5);
        jellybeanCount = util.getJellybeans(); 
        Util.printAnimatedText("You now have " + jellybeanCount + 
        jellybeans!")'

    }
```

Comment: Again, this is true, but, why is needed the new variable/field jellybeanCount? in the Util class, alerady exist that field

Comment: @DamianLattenero Because it makes the code flow a bit more smoothly?  It probably doesn't make much difference in this example, but there are lots of times when it makes code more readable to use intermediate variables so that you don't have a bunch of more complex expressions all stuck together in one larger statement.

Comment: The jellybeans method is void therefore you need another method util.getJellybeans() to make a reference to the class variable assuming all variables were local. You would have to call getJellybeans() that returns an int before printing.

Comment: @ajb aaaah... I see... But like I see a sort of "getter/setter" involved here, I thought it was unnecessary at all, maybe I was wrong, I will edit my answer to try to explain it

Comment: @Juniar yes, that's true... if you want, see the other alternative I answered. anyway, this answer is ok. Is a plus one in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

Since int is primitive type and not set by reference in

```
private int jellybeanCount= ...
```

you might want to modify this method below to return a value

```
 public int jellybeans(int Amount){
     return Jellybeans + Amount;
 }
```

And invoke it as below

```
    jellybeanCount = util.jellybeans(5);
    Util.printAnimatedText("You now have " + jellybeanCount + " 
    jellybeans!")'
```